# SQL Distinct and * combination under

Tags: sql

I know what `select count(distinct country) from customer` does.

But I can't understand what this

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT Country) 
FROM Customers;
```

does.

Can anyone explain?

(use this link to enter the codes which I am asking about)  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct2

Comment: That's easy.  The second should return an error in any reasonable database.  Even the most recent version of MySQL doesn't allow this syntax by default.

Comment: The second query is invalid SQL and shows once again how bad w3fools is.

Comment: w3schools has some weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing:

```
create table #test (Country varchar(10), Otherthings varchar(20))
insert into #test(Country,Otherthings) values ('UK','Something'),('USA','Something else')

SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT Country) 
FROM #test
```

Produces:

```
> Column '#test.Country' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT Country) FROM Customers;
```

Will provide you a row with a column, count(number of unique country's name).
And I don't think it will create an error, like someone said. I tried it and it's working.

Comment: No it will not provide you with any row. It will simply fail with an error:

Answer (score -2):

you get the count of countries in the customer Table.. here DISTINCT keyword is used for avoiding duplication count. example: country list is INDIA,INDIA,SPAIN,GERMANY,SPAIN then the count is 3.